# jquery not hiding unselected tabs on php page hosted on xampp server

Tags: php, jquery, html, local-storage

I have the following php code. I used jquery to create tabs in it. But jquery is not working on the php page. Whenever I load the php page on localhost using xampp both tabs get displayed. I searched for the problem but still not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>jQuery Tabs Demo</title>
    <style>
        * {padding:0; margin:0;}

        html {
            background:url(/img/tiles/wood.png) 0 0 repeat;
            padding:15px 15px 0;
            font-family:sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
        }

        p, h3 { 
            margin-bottom:15px;
        }

        div {
            padding:10px;
            width:600px;
            background:#fff;
        }

        .tabs li {
            list-style:none;
            display:inline;
        }

        .tabs a {
            padding:5px 10px;
            display:inline-block;
            background:#D8D8D8;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        .tabs a.active {
            background:#666 ;
            color:#FFFFFF ;
        }


    </style>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('ul.tabs').each(function ()
    {

        var index = "key";
        //  Define friendly data store name
    //  Start magic!
    try
    {
        alert('i am in try');
        // getter: Fetch previous value
        var oldIndex = parseInt(local.getItem(index));
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert('i m in catch');
        // getter: Always default to first tab in error state
        var oldIndex = 0;
    }


    alert('oldIndex' + oldIndex);
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[oldIndex]);

    $active.addClass('active');

    $content = $($active[0].hash);

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function ()
    {
        $(this.hash).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e)
    {
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $(this.hash);

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        if (location.hash == '#details')
            var newIndex = "1";
        else
            var newIndex = "0";

        //  Set future value
        localStorage.setItem(index, newIndex)


        // Prevent the anchor's default click action

    });



    });
});




</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class='tabs'>
            <li><a href="#count" >Count</a></li>
            <li><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id='count'>
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <?php include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Login Page\countpage.php';?>
        </div>
        <div id='details'>
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi laoreet magna vitae est mollis ultricies. Mauris eget enim ac justo eleifend malesuada. Proin non consectetur est. Integer semper laoreet porta. Praesent facilisis leo nec libero tincidunt blandit.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above jquery code is also used to remain on the selected tab after refresh. The code doesn't seem to work. Please help.

**Edit :**  I have edited the code to include localStorage of HTML5. But the localStorage is not storing any value. Because of that jquery  is not able to extract the stored values from localStorage in try block. Please help to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BYUdS/303/).

I think you had one typo

```
$content = $($active[0].hash);
```

should be:

```
$content = $($active.hash);
```

**EDIT:** new fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BYUdS/335/)

basically I think location.hash is not doing what you expected it to do. How I fixed it was to get the href with a different way, `newIndex = $(this).attr('href');` and pass to your `$active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[oldIndex]);` thingy `+oldIndex+` instead of `+location.hash+`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working. Only problem now is I want the first tab to be shown when it loads for the first time and selected tab to be shown after refresh. But the code is still not showing the selected tab after refresh.

Comment: Hm, are you sure this functionality is already written in the code?? I think the only way to do this on page reload is with cookies, store in a cookie which one is active and then re-assign it as active, could be wrong though..!

Comment: Yes, I have used sessionStorage of HTML5 in my code. I am using dataStore.setItem(index,newIndex) to store the index of selected tab into index variable and retrieving the value using dataStore.getItem() in the try block.

Comment: Ah I see. Did you also try it on your server? Fiddle might preventing some functonality

Comment: I tried it on xampp server. Still not working. Neither any default tab is getting shown when I first load the page nor the selected tab is getting displayed after refresh.

Comment: did some tests, here is a new http://jsfiddle.net/BYUdS/310/, basically, I just added some alerts to show you some information. It seems the on click part has some mistakes as it is not saving the right thing

Comment: I think the main problem is that the jquery is not using setItem and getItem of HTML5 sessionStorage

Comment: judging from the alerts in the fiddle I would say the problem is with the location.hash, its always undefined, dont think html5 and jquery dont get along, bottom line i dont think you are getting the href values

Comment: sorry check again forgot to submit :P

Comment: Regarding your edit on your question. @Aisarangh Check my answer again, as I told you the storage was working fine, but you misunderstood the `location.hash` function. Fiddle is working as expected!

Comment: Now it is showing me both tab contents in js fiddle.