# jquery not showing currently clicked tab's href value

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

Below is my HTML code. I have used alert to display the currently clicked tab's href value. But when I click on any tab it  is showing me the value of last clicked tab's href value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>jQuery Tabs Demo</title>
        <style>
            * {padding:0; margin:0;}

            html {
                background:url(/img/tiles/wood.png) 0 0 repeat;
                padding:15px 15px 0;
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size:14px;
            }

            p, h3 { 
                margin-bottom:15px;
            }

            div {
                padding:10px;
                width:600px;
                background:#fff;
            }

            .tabs li {
                list-style:none;
                display:inline;
            }

            .tabs a {
                padding:5px 10px;
                display:inline-block;
                background:#D8D8D8;
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none;
            }

            .tabs a.active {
                background:#666 ;
                color:#FFFFFF ;
            } 
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
                    var index = "key";
                    //  Define friendly data store name
                    //  Start magic!
                    try {
                        // getter: Fetch previous value
                        var oldIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(index));

                    } catch(e) {  
                        // getter: Always default to first tab in error state
                        var oldIndex = 0;
                    }

                    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
                    // which tab is active and it's associated content
                    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

                    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[oldIndex]);
                    $active.addClass('active');

                    $content = $($active[0].hash);

                    // Hide the remaining content
                    $links.not($active).each(function () {
                        $(this.hash).hide();
                    });

                    // Bind the click event handler
                    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e)
                    {     
                        var id=$(this).attr('href');
                        alert('location ='+id);
                        // Make the old tab inactive.


                        $active.removeClass('active');
                        $content.hide();

                        // Update the variables with the new link and content
                        $active = $(this);
                        $content = $(this.hash);

                        // Make the tab active.
                        $active.addClass('active');
                        $content.show();

                        if(location.hash=='#details')
                            var newIndex="1";
                        else
                            var newIndex="0";

                        //  Set future value
                        localStorage.setItem(index,newIndex) ;

                        alert('localstoarge '+parseInt(localStorage.getItem(index)));
                        // Prevent the anchor's default click action

                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class='tabs'>
            <li><a href="#count" >Count</a></li>
            <li><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id='count'>
            <h3>Count</h3>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
        <div id='details'>
            <h3>Details</h3>
            <p>Suspendisse potenti. 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried everything to display the current value. But no luck. Please help me to identify the mistake in the code.
**Edit:** The above code is run on xampp server.

Comment: There's a lot going on here, and one of the things apparent immediately is that you define your index and oldindex variables inside blocks, and then do nothing with them inside those blocks. Those variables are out of scope outside of those blocks, and hence cannot be used. So when you access index or oldindex anywhere outside of the ready() function, they are gone.

Comment: First fix the console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined `

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem http://jsfiddle.net/qSALk/

Comment: possible duplicate from the same user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902956/jquery-not-hiding-unselected-tabs-on-php-page-hosted-on-xampp-server/24903123#24903123

Comment: @Spokey the code runs fine on xampp server. I don't know why it is showing the output like that in js fiddle.

Comment: @Aisarangh it does not matter since javascript is client side. Please complete the jsFiddle so it will work like it does on your localhost and see if you still get the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told you on the previous post you did with the same exact question. You seem to misunderstand what `location.hash does` as you can see in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BYUdS/335/) it is working as expected, because am getting your href values correctly.

```
newIndex = $(this).attr('href');
```

instead of

```
var newIndex = $links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0];
```

[**Working fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BYUdS/335/)

> Keeps information on reload
>
> Tabs change correctly and show correct information

Comment: for some reason js fiddle is not showing me the same result as you are saying. As I have said it is showing me both tabs contents. I am using internet explorer 9

Comment: why would you use ie9!, on a more serious side, maybe you should have mentioned that before making a duplicate question of your own question..!

Comment: Also, with the infotmaton given, you should be able to see what works on ie9 or not, unfortunately, i dont have such an old version of ie

Comment: thanks for solving my question. Code is working now :)